# How to refresh view.py in Django when clicking form checkbox and passing checkbox boolean?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

Hello I'm trying to refresh my webpage when clicking a form checkbox and passing the checkbox boolean to the view.py.

I'm trying to accomplish this using Ajax, but this is the first time using Ajax and I honestly have no idea if its working correctly.

HTML and AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#check_legend").change(function(){
      var form_data = $("#form_legend").serialize();
          $.ajax({ url: '/api/post_form/',
                              type: "POST",
                              dataType: "json",
                              data: {form_data: form_data},
                              //cache: false
                     }).done(function(data) {
                          if (data.result === true){
                              alert(data.message);
                         }
                     });
                });
</script>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      {{ map|safe }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <form method="post" id="form_legend">
        <h3><span style="color: #e8c4b4;">Places</span></h3>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_legend" name="cities">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="check_legend">Cities</label>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is in my url.py if it's of any use:

```
path('api/post_form/', post_form_api, name="post_form_api")
```

and my view.py goes as follows for the ajax response:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def post_form_api(request):
      data = {}
      if request.method == "POST" and request.POST.get('cities', None) is not None:
          form_field1 = request.POST.get('cities')
          # save the form data and indicate success
          data['result'] = True
          data['message'] = "Form saved successfully"
          ...
      if request.is_ajax():
         return JsonResponse(data)
      else:
         return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

In a different part of the view.py where I get give values to the webpage I handle the POST request like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST.get['cities', False]:
```

Comment: Are there any errors? Try printing `request.POST.get('form_data')` Tell me what you see...

Comment: @MoiMyazz If I do that after ``` if request.method == 'POST': ``` I don't get anything when I check and uncheck the checkbox. Doesn't seem to trigger anything. I don't even get anything in my console log the first time I open the webpage.

Comment: No bro, try the print statement `request.POST.get('form_data')` above the `if request.method == 'POST':` You should see something like a `QueryDic` object.

Comment: Sadly nothing like that is showing up if I try it above the if statement, could this be because I have the form data not saved in a model? I was trying to make this work without a model.

Comment: No bro, a model form is not the problem here... This seems it is from the front-end. update your Ajax call... `url: '/api/post_form/',` `//cache: false`, `data: {form_data: form_data}`. Try those and tell me what you get

Comment: I did, it gives the same result as before, I will update my post so you can see what the current HTML looks like.

Comment: If you try `console.log('Checked')` when the box is checked as it is now, I don't think you will be able to see "Checked" because where you have `$("check_legend").click(function(){...}` is not actually referring to your checkbox. Adding the selector by `#check_legend` is what you want. `$("#check_legend")`. And you might want to use `$("#check_legend").change(function(){...}` if the `$("#check_legend").click(function(){...}` doesn't work.

Comment: I did try the options you have given me, none of them seem to work. I also changed `form_legend` to `#form_legend`. I do get a `None` in my console log from `request.POST.get('form_data')` when I refresh the page by myself. I will refresh my original post to reflect what my script on the HTML page looks like now. Thanks for your continuous help and replies.

Comment: Have you seen `None` even if you have checked the checkbox?

Comment: Yes, `None` appears when checked or unchecked. But only when reloading the page.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
window.location.reload()
```